# How to get posts whose user profession is a special case in laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, orm

This is a social media app.

1. **users** table has **id**, **name**, **email**, **password** fields.
2. **posts** table has **id**, **user_id**, **caption** and other fields.
3. **professions** table has **id** , **title** fields
4. **users_professions** table has **id** , **user_id**  fields
5. Each user has many posts.
6. User "**hasMany**" posts, Post "**belongsTo**" a User.
7. Each **user** has one **users_professions**.
8. User "**hasOne**" **users_professions**.

Question:

I want to get "posts" who Their user profession equal the selected ID.

My current code :

```php
$posts = Post::join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.user_id')
    ->join('users_professions', 'users.id', '=', 'users_professions.user_id')
    ->where('users_professions.profession_id', $request->category_id)
    ->where('files', "<>", "[]")
    ->where('is_product', 0)
    ->select('posts.id', 'posts.title', 'posts.user_id', 'posts.is_product', 'posts.media_display_mode', 'posts.files','posts.created_at')
    ->orderBy('posts.id', 'desc')
    ->paginate(50);
```

Is this code correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your code. If all you care about is retrieving the `Posts` based on a condition tied to their relationships, you could use the `whereHas` method.

[Eloquent Relationships - Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

Assuming the following relationships are defined in your models:

- `Post` `belongsTo` `User` (as `user()`)
- `User` `belongsToMany` `Profession` (as `professions()`)

```php
// Query only the posts that belong to an user who has a profession with id = $profession_id
Post::whereHas('user.professions', function ($professions) use ($profession_id) {
    $professions->where('professions.id', $profession_id);
})
...
->get()
```

Or assuming the following relationships are defined in your models:

- `Post` `belongsTo` `User` (as `user()`)
- `User` `hasMany` (or `hasOne`) `ProfessionUser` (as `professions_user()`)

```php
// Query only the posts that belong to an user who has a profession_user with profession_id = $profession_id
Post::whereHas('user.professions_user', function ($professions_user) use ($profession_id) {
    $professions_user->where('profession_user.professions_id', $profession_id);
})
...
->get()
```